# UserModel.findOne returns an object with members duplicated inside member: _doc

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using `Node`, `Passport`, `LocalStrategy`, `Mongoose` for one simple project, and have 2 questions...

1. why the `user` element returned by `UserModel.findOne(...)` has the members I expect it has: `{ _id, local, facebook, google, twitter, createdAt, updatedAt }`, but all these members are also (duplicated) inside its member: `_doc`?

[image]

when I expand the `_doc` member, I get:

[image]

2. what's the type of the variable: `user`?

Could you clarify these 2 questions for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_doc` is the raw js object.
`user` is the mongoose [Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html), that inherits javascript `Object`.

Mongoose provides a lot of different APIs, that are included in the Document object.

While `_doc` will just have the APIs that a normal javascript object offers.